# How to stop a thread after some time in java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my android app I am having a thread in which I fetch data from a web service.
So normally it works well, but sometimes if the connection is too slow it kind of hangs.
So is there any way by which I can set some time say 1 min, and if the thread process is not
completed in 1 min. then I would like to stop this thread and display a message to the user that connection is weak/slow and try later.
Please help !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Killing thread after some specified time limit in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733356/killing-thread-after-some-specified-time-limit-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether it is supported in Android, but this is exactly what the [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) objects returned from an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) are supposed to do for you. In particular, the [cancel(boolean)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) method can be used to interrupt the task if it has started but not finished.

The tasks should be written to be aware that they may be interrupted, and abort cleanly if they have been. Most of the framework IO methods can be interrupted, so you just need to worry about your own code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea. The `Thread.stop` method is deprecated for good reasons.

I suggest you do the following: Set the network time-outs according to your preferences. If this doesn't help, I suggest that you simply throw away the reference to the thread, (ignore it, let it die out and get garbage collected) and respond with a nice message about network failure. You can very well start a new thread for trying again.

Comment: Letting the thread be garbage collected is the correct way, your code should support that. When an error happens for me I close down my socket connection, delete any observers and the thread is nicely shut down by Android for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method : `Thread.interrupt();`
the method ***Thread.stop()*** is deprecated

Comment: can you tell me for example what you want to do with this timer, in order to figure out a solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Create a stop method like this, and call interrupt subsequently.

```
public void stop() {
    Thread currentThread= someThread;
    someThread= null;
    currentThread.interrupt();
}
```