# time limit for Process.waitFor

Tags: java

Is there a way (either builtin, or with external library) to have a time limit for `Process.waitFor`? It's a good safeguard against buggy processes, and implementing it with an extra thread and an interrupt seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Have you looked at [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)?

Comment: You might be interested in ExecutorService which has timeouts builtin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733356/killing-thread-after-some-specified-time-limit-in-java

Comment: @miku ExecutorService is a thread in disguise. It's rather low level. I'd rather something builting that would allow me, say to destroy the process if timeout exceeds. `Processes.waitFor(p,100)` is more readable than `svc.execute(new Runnable() {void run() {p.waitFor;}....)`